# How to create Listing screen with custom images in android?

Tags: android

I'm newbie to android, i'm creating a app in which i required listing screen what i tried is below in my code. I requie a very simple listing screen, Could anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >


<!--  Left side Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/doc"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of Song-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="love you the"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Mary" />

<!-- Rightend Duration -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="7:45"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrows"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try using a TableLayout?

Comment: @ Abhishek , ya but 2nd text (artist name) not able to align below Title of song